# flutter inspector devtools details tab D means?

Tags: flutter

In devtools of `Flutter Inspector`, under `details Tree` tab, some of the properties are marked with capital `D` while others are not.

The official docs https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector has no mention of it.

What does `D` stands for ?

Answer (score 0):

The `D` stands for `Default Value` in details tree tab.

If any property is having a default value which hasn't been changed, than it will be marked with `D`.